# nginx vhost site priority

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I heed some help figuring out why my nginx is prioritising the site this way. I have server blocks in my vhost:

```
server { #site 1
    listen 80;
    server_name site1.testing.domain.com$;
    root /var/www/site1/web;
    # further config
}

server { #site 2
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<sname>.+?).testing.domain.com$;
    root /var/www/$sname/public;
    # further fonfig
}
```

Based on nginx documentation, it should prioritize the domain that matches fully first, but when i go on to http://site1.testing.domain.com it loads config from site 2. (If I remove the confing for dynamic subdomain, then the site 1 config works fine).

Can someone explain what am i doing wrong or why is nginx behaving this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: The first variant doesn't match due to the `$` at the end of the `server_name`, which is invalid as this isn't a regex.